# Custom Payload not working in Google DialogFlow ES

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am sending a simple custom payload copied from official docs. Here is the payload ->

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "accordion",
        "title": "Accordion title",
        "subtitle": "Accordion subtitle",
        "text": "Accordion text"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The intent is not attached to any previous intents, and I am not sending response through the backend. Instead, I am sending it through the "Response Section", built-in in the Dialogflow console.

The problem is that DialogFlow is not able to identify this custom payload, although the intent works alright when a text response is sent instead.

PS:- The scenario is the same when instead of using the built-in console, I send the response through the backend. Dialogflow understands simple text response but fails to process the custom payload.

Here is the screenshots ->

[image]

[image]

Comment: The custom payload is made mainly for Dialogflow Messenger like Ricco D mentioned not for Try it me section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom payload should work if you ran your test in [Dialogflow Messenger Integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger) as it supports [accordion response type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#accordion_response_type). See test below using your custom payload:

[image]

Intent configuration:

[image]

Comment: Got it! Custom payload is not shown in console. We can see it in text based integration